# Глубина цвета пикселя encoder paramters

Tags: c++, color, format

есть программа, которая должна преобразовывать из 8-bit ного Bmp в 8-bit jpeg, но она преобразовывает его в 24bit jpeg. За преобразования отвечают эти строки:

- encoderParameters.Count = 1;
- encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderColorDepth; //глубина
  цвета (новый параметр)
- encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1; // количество
  значений параметра
- //encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type =
  EncoderParameterValueTypeLong; //тип значения параметра.
- PixelFormat depth = PixelFormat8bppIndexed; //198659
- encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &depth; //его значение и
  ссылка на него
- stat = image->Save(L"Shapes01.jpg", &encoderClsid,
  &encoderParameters);

На практике: картинке вообще всё равно на этот параметр- т.е. она игнорирует значение PixelFormat(можно написать туда PixelFormat4bppIndexed и сохранит ту же картинку), в чём может быть дело? При чём, получая image->GetPixelFormat() получаю значение всегда 198659 , что соответствует 8 bit.

Comment: 8-битный jpeg бывает только в градациях серого, а 8-битный битмап имеет палитру. Это не смущает?

Comment: это окей, интересно как просто сохранить 8bit jpeg , если он уже в градациях серого.